# Java - Get position in code (Package/Class/Method)

Tags: java, error-handling

OK, may be a silly question.
I am working on a java project and I want to be able to easily get the position of my current code, namely Package/Class/Method, and print it to output.

For example, I want to output the Package/Class/Method info in errory cases, in order to be able to recognize the exact method in which the error occurs.

Is there a code that can give me this info?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have `stacktrace` by `JVM` it contains all these info just log it.

Or *programatically* if you want to determine

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```

According to the [*Javadocs*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace%28%29):

> [...] the first element of the array represents the top of the stack, which is the most recent method invocation in the sequence. The last element of the array represents the bottom of the stack, which is the least recent method invocation in the sequence.

A StackTraceElement has `getClassName()`, `getFileName()`, `getLineNumber()` and `getMethodName()`.

Comment: Well, the least recent method will probably be main or something similar. The OP probably wants the opposite: the most recent.

Comment: @martinho `stackTraceElements ` contains all the info

Comment: @org.life.java: problem is you have no idea of where in that array is the "current method". The most recent (index 0) will probably be `getStackTrace` or something called in there. Anything in between is certainly not guaranteed. Printing out the whole stack helps, but you cannot rely on it to learn the current method.

Comment: @Mart oth will be `getStacktrace` and 1 will be desired `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName()`

Comment: @org.life.java: No, [1] is not the desired position. If you're running on Sun's JVM 1.5, it happens to be in position [2]. On other JVMs or other versions it can be [1], [2], [3], whatever. Even [0] is possible, because the JVM is allowed to omit stack frames. You have **no guarantees**.

Comment: A somewhat more reliable (still not 100% guaranteed) but way uglier solution is `new Exception().getStackTrace()[0]`. According to the docs "The zeroth element of the array (assuming the array's length is non-zero) represents the top of the stack, which is the last method invocation in the sequence. *Typically*, this is the point at which this throwable was created and thrown." (emphasis mine). The problem (other than the word *tipically*) is that the JVM is still allowed to omit frames, so the current method could be missing from it.

Answer (score 4):

Create an exception when you have an error. If you want to print it to console you can then call the `exception.printstacktrace();` method on the exception.

It's better practice to use a logging framework like log4j you can do `logger.error( "message", exception );` and you'll get a stacktrace in your log.

Answer (score 2):

dont go for such a complex solution.

If you are using log4j your already done.
Use a pattern like this: %-5p %d [%t] %C{1}.%M(%L): %m%n

%t is the current Thread
%C{1} is the Name of the Class (omit the {1} and you get the full qualified name with package)
%M is the Name of the Method
%L is the line number
for any details check here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html

Keep in mind that login the name of the Method or the line number will degrade performance.
Never do this in a production system.

Comment: +1 for using a feature of the logging system, rather than do-it-yourself